# Is it possible to set a dotenv file with rails server command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, environment

Is it possible to pass a specific dotenv file along with the `rails s` command when starting up a server (something like `rails s --dotenv .env.ssl`)? I'd like to start my local rails application with ssl (and therefore different environment variables) and in normal mode, where it would just load my normal `.env` file or something of the kind.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv), it doesn't appear to have any command line flag like that, however, where you call `Dotenv.load` you can pass in files `Dotenv.load('file1.env', 'file2.env')` so you can handle it manually (look for the flag or a specific ENV variable to determine which additional files to load). Alternatively, in the Frequently Asked Questions on the README it mentions

> dotenv-rails will load the following files, starting from the bottom. The first value set (or those already defined in the environment) take precedence:
>
> .env - The Original®
>
> .env.development, .env.test, .env.production - Environment-specific settings.
>
> .env.local - Local overrides. This file is loaded for all environments except test.
>
> .env.development.local, .env.test.local, .env.production.local - Local overrides of environment-specific settings.

So I believe this would mean your normal .env would be .env.local and things that you want in your SSH would be .env, without the need for a flag.